# Can arguments of max() function be factored out when multiplied?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, factoring

$$\max(x_1-k_1,0)^2=\max(x_1-k_1,0)\max(x_1-k_1,0)$$

Is the following true?

$$\max(x_1-k_1,0)\max(x_1-k_1,0)=(x_1-k_1)\max(x_1-k_1,0)$$

And more generally...

$$\max(x_1-k_1,0)\max(x_2-k_2,0)=(x_2-k_2)\max(x_1-k_1,0)$$

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have outlined is incorrect - Let us simplify the problem
$$
\max(k, 0)^2
$$
is what you want to find. If we assume what you say
$$
\max(k, 0)\max(k, 0) = k\max(k, 0)
$$
then it is clear you have already assumed that $\max(k, 0) = k$ so why not the other? since they are the same.
Lets look at the cases
$$
\max(k, 0)\max(k, 0) = \cases{k^2 \;\; k >0 \\ 0 \;\; k \leq 0}
$$
this suggests that we have
$$
\max(k, 0)\max(k, 0) = \max(k^2, 0)
$$
now the general case
$$
\max(k, 0)\max(m, 0) = \cases{km \;\; k > 0, m > 0\\ k\cdot 0 \;\;k > 0, m \leq 0\\ m \cdot 0 \;\;k \leq 0, m > 0\\ 0 \;\;k \leq 0, m \leq 0}
$$
can you work out a max of the above.

Comment: Is it $\max(km,0)$?

Comment: yes. when $k <0$ then $km < 0$ so we have $0$ etc.